# Pure geometry proof for triangle problem

Tags: geometry, triangles

Here is the orthologic triangles theorem:

> $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$ are triangles in the same plane. If the perpendiculars from $A$, $B$ and $C$ to $B'C'$, $C'A'$ and $A'B'$ respectively are concurrent, prove that so are the perpendiculars from $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$ to $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ respectively.

In my book two solutions have been given using coordinate geometry and [another using vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525821/prove-that-the-perpendiculars-from-p-q-r-to-bc-ca-ab-respectively-are-also-concu). But I was wondering if you can solve this using pure geometry. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall well-known lemma:

**Lemma 1.** Let $D,E,F$ be points on lines $BC, CA, AB$. Then lines perpendicular to $BC, CA, AB$ through $D,E,F$ are concurrent if and only if $BD^2+CE^2+AF^2=DC^2+EA^2+FB^2$.

Recall another known lemma:

**Lemma 2.** For any points $A,B,C,D$ the following equivalence holds: $AC \perp BD \iff AB^2+CD^2=BC^2+DA^2$.

We can easily generalize lemma 1 using lemma 2 to the following

**Lemma 3.** Let $A,B,C,D,E,F$ be any points. Then lines perpendicular to $BC, CA, AB$ through $D,E,F$ are concurrent if and only if $BD^2+CE^2+AF^2=DC^2+EA^2+FB^2$.

Now we are ready to prove the theorem.

First, we put $(A,B,C,D,E,F):=(A',B',C',A,B,C)$ in lemma 3 and we get the equality $$B'A^2+C'B^2+A'C^2=AC'^2+BA'^2+CB'^2.$$ Now we put $(A,B,C,D,E,F)=(A,B,C,A',B',C')$ in lemma 3 and conclude that the equality above implies that perpendiculars to $BC, CA, AB$ through $A',B',C'$ are concurrent. $\square$

Comment: Are there particular names for these lemmas?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I don't know. Probably not.

Comment: @user34304: The first lemma is known as [Carnot's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Carnot.shtml) (not to be confused with [Carnot's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/carnot.shtml)). Before realizing this, I called the result "Ortha's Theorem" in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/652127/409), where I provided a proof.

Answer (score -1):

There is a rotation and scaling (without translation) with respect to  *common  orthocenter*  of ABC and A'B'C'. Thus the two triangles are duals, or, alternately belong to a set of dialation/rotation transforms.

So its proof is easier ( I believe) with complex number sets.

Comment: Triangles ABC and A'B'C' don't have to have a common orthocenter.